# How to download entire shared folder on Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is it possible to download entire folder with all files in it the easy way from someone else's Ubuntu One account (if that folder is shared for me)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to download an entire folder that has been shared to you, from the web site. You need to install the client application, and subscribe to the shared folder, so that it is synchronized to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add bookmarklet from http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/02/29/downloading-all-the-files-in-an-ubuntu-one-folder/ to (only) Chrome browser to download all files via web interface with single click.

Tip: turn off to ask where to save download in Chrome before launching to prevent billions of "Save As" dialogs.